# Brightness controller not working after screen replaced

Tags: macbook-pro

[image]

it's an A1706 EMC 3163  any idea? if it's software or the screen it self?

Comment: Who did replace the screen?

Comment: Me? :P I think the screen doesn't have the ambiance ... sensor is the cause